# Flask LoginManager breaks Flask application

Tags: python, flask

I've been trying to implement user authentication to a flask app, but I cannot import LoginManager from flask_login. It breaks the Werkzeug package.

I tried installing previous versions of Werkzeug and Flask-Login, did it on multiple fresh environments, even ditched anaconda completely but nothing worked.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/erykw/porsche_website/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blog import app
  File "/Users/erykw/porsche_website/blog/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from flask_login import LoginManager
  File "/Users/erykw/porsche_website/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_login/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .login_manager import LoginManager
  File "/Users/erykw/porsche_website/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_login/login_manager.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .utils import _create_identifier
  File "/Users/erykw/porsche_website/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 14, in <module>
    from werkzeug.urls import url_decode
ImportError: cannot import name 'url_decode' from 'werkzeug.urls' (/Users/erykw/porsche_website/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/werkzeug/urls.py)
```

Pip freeze:

```
bcrypt==4.0.1
blinker==1.6.2
click==8.1.7
dnspython==2.4.2
email-validator==2.0.0.post2
Flask==3.0.0
Flask-Bcrypt==1.0.1
Flask-Login==0.6.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1
Flask-WTF==1.2.1
idna==3.4
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
SQLAlchemy==2.0.21
typing_extensions==4.8.0
Werkzeug==3.0.0
WTForms==3.0.1
```

Tree:

```
.
├── FETCH_HEAD
├── README.md
├── blog
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-311.pyc
│   │   ├── forms.cpython-311.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-311.pyc
│   │   └── routes.cpython-311.pyc
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── main.css
│   └── templates
│       ├── about.html
│       ├── home.html
│       ├── layout.html
│       ├── login.html
│       └── register.html
├── instance
│   └── site.db
└── run.py
```

Comment: upgrade flask_login to 0.6.3. They fixed compatibility with werkzeug 3
https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/0.6.3/CHANGES.md

Answer (score 1):

This might already have an answer here

[ImportError: cannot import name 'url_decode' from 'werkzeug.urls'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77215107/importerror-cannot-import-name-url-decode-from-werkzeug-urls)

ie, downgrade werkzeug to version 2.3.0 until it is sorted out

Werkzeug==2.3.0

Comment: Thank you, no idea how I missed that post. Sorry for repeating the question.

Comment: thats ok, you can still upvote or accept the answer, but your question will probably be closed as a duplicate. dont worry about it, and welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with backward compatibility with Werkzeug 3.0 update. With the new release of [Flask-login](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Login/#history) to version 0.6.3 on Oct 30, 2023, this issue is fixed.

The following version of packages work fine together:

```yaml
Werkzeug==3.0.0
Flask-Login==0.6.3
Flask==3.0.0
```