# Cannot import name 'url_decode' from 'werkzeug.urls'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Projects\Python Based\Web Framework\Flask\LoginPage> flask run --debug
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.
Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Projects\Python Based\Web Framework\Flask\LoginPage\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 219, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Projects\Python Based\Web Framework\Flask\LoginPage\app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_login import UserMixin
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Projects\Python Based\Web Framework\Flask\LoginPage\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_login\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .login_manager import LoginManager
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Projects\Python Based\Web Framework\Flask\LoginPage\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_login\login_manager.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .utils import _create_identifier
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Projects\Python Based\Web Framework\Flask\LoginPage\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 14, in <module>
    from werkzeug.urls import url_decode
ImportError: cannot import name 'url_decode' from 'werkzeug.urls' (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Projects\Python Based\Web Framework\Flask\LoginPage\.venv\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\urls.py)
```

- How can I fix this ?
- I have updated all libraries
  _ I have created code from scratch
  _ I have checked everything but can't solve problem

Comment: Is `url_decode` installed? Is it install location listed in your PYTHONPATH env variable?

Comment: How I can check that?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have Werkzeug 3.0.0

try downgrading it to this version : 2.3

Comment: Still not working, my rest of the libraries are working it's only creating problem with flask-login

Comment: downgrading Werkzeug to 2.3 solved my problem with this error.

Answer (score 0):

The core issue for this was with the flask-login package was incompatible with Flask/Werkzeug 3.0.0. This is now fixed in flask-login v0.6.3, that went live on 2023-10-31.

You need to update to latest package of flask-login and this is resolved.

https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/releases/tag/0.6.3